flutter CICD failed on while run on ubuntu-latest
i am trying to create a cicd for my flutter app but if i run on runs-on: ubuntu-latest it will fail but if i run on runs-on: macos-latest it will not show that error,
here is the error
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform-Tools accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.2".
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.2" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform-Tools in /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/platform-tools
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.2" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.35.0.2" finished.
lib/main.dart:22:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/Network/services/navigator_service.dart': No such file or directory
import 'Network/services/navigator_service.dart';
       ^
lib/helper/widget/custom_button.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/helper/TextStyle.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/helper/TextStyle.dart';
       ^
lib/providers/profile_provider.dart:2:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/Network/services/navigator_service.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/Network/services/navigator_service.dart';
       ^
lib/helper/widget/empty_data_screens.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/Network/services/navigator_service.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/Network/services/navigator_service.dart';
       ^
lib/helper/widget/empty_data_screens.dart:6:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/helper/TextStyle.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/helper/TextStyle.dart';
       ^
lib/helper/widget/transactions/transactions_widgets.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/helper/TextStyle.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/helper/TextStyle.dart';
       ^
lib/helper/widget/upload_response.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/helper/TextStyle.dart': No such file or directory
import 'package:purse_money/helper/TextStyle.dart';
       ^

but all this run fine runs-on: macos-latest
here is my full code
name: Deploy to App Stores

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Java
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: 'oracle'
        java-version: '17'
    
    - name: Set up Flutter
      uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
      with:
        flutter-version: '3.24.3'
        channel: 'stable'
        cache: true

    - name: Install Android SDK
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y wget unzip
        wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip
        mkdir -p $HOME/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
        unzip commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip -d $HOME/android-sdk/cmdline-tools
        export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android-sdk
        export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools/bin:$PATH
        export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
        yes | sdkmanager --licenses
        sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-33" "build-tools;33.0.0"

      
    - name: Increment version
      run: |
        version=$(grep 'version:' pubspec.yaml | sed 's/version: //')
        major=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f1)
        minor=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f2)
        patch=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f3 | cut -d+ -f1)
        build=$(echo $version | cut -d+ -f2)
        
        new_build=$((build + 1))
        new_version="$major.$minor.$patch+$new_build"
        sed -i "s/^version: .*$/version: $new_version/" pubspec.yaml
        
        echo "New version: $new_version"

      # Read the current version -- this is for macos 
        # version=$(grep 'version:' pubspec.yaml | sed 's/version: //')
        # major=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f1)
        # minor=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f2)
        # patch=$(echo $version | cut -d. -f3 | cut -d+ -f1)
        # build=$(echo $version | cut -d+ -f2)
        
        # # Increment build number
        # new_build=$((build + 1))
        
        # new_version="$major.$minor.$patch+$new_build"
        # # Update pubspec.yaml with the new version
        # sed -i '' "s/^version: .*$/version: $new_version/" pubspec.yaml
        
        # echo "New version: $new_version"
  
    - name: Setup Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: '3.0'

    - name: Clean Flutter build and pub cache
      run: flutter clean

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: flutter pub get

    - name: Build flutter debug apk
      run: flutter build apk --debug

    - name: List APK files
      run: ls build/app/outputs/flutter-apk

    - name: Upload artifact to Firebase App Distribution
      uses: wzieba/Firebase-Distribution-Github-Action@v1.2.1
      with:
        appId: 1:
        #${{secrets.APP_ID}}
        serviceCredentialsFileContent: ${{secrets.CREDENTIAL_FILE_CONTENT}}
        file: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk

the error is at the point build in
- name: Build flutter debug apk
  run: flutter build apk --debug

